# Upgrading Old Desktop Computer

Tags: desktop-computer

I have an old PC, **Dell Optiplex GX520** but it is not efficient anymore. I'd like to upgrade it but I don't know if it's possible to do it without having any compatibility problems. I chose this hardware components so far:

- Processor BX80662I36100 Intel Dual-Core i3-610 3.70Ghz / **$2,309.00 MXN**
- RAM Kingston 8 GB DDR4 / **$1,123.33 MXN**
- Motherboard ASUS DDR4 S1151 Micro-ATX / **$1,368.00 MXN**
- HDD Western Digital Caviar Blue 3.5'' 1TB SATA III / **$1,068.00 MXN**

**Information about my current PC:**

- (GX520) Minitower: 230 W
- Windows XP Service Pack 3
- Intel Pentium 4 CPU 3.00GHz
- 0.99 GB RAM

**My questions/concern are the following:**

First of all, Can I really upgrade this computer?

Can I use the same power supply with the new components?

Can the Minitower Chasis still be used?

What do you suggest me to upgrade without elevating the cost?

**More Information:**

1. The computer is used for video and image editing.
2. I just want to make the computer more efficient and a little bit
   more fast. I want to change the SO Windows XP to Windows 7 but the
   computer does not have the capacity to keep going without lagging,
   it even does so with the Windows XP and there are many software
   updates that do not support Windows XP anymore.
3. I live in Mexico.
4. **My budget**: Less than $6,000.00 MXN ($291.57 USD approximately)

**Beforehand, thank you.**

Comment: Hardware recommendations are not on topic here at Superuser

Comment: " Questions seeking for hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic because they are often relevant only to the question author at the time the question was asked and tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead of asking what to buy, try asking how to find out what suits your needs."

Comment: If you change the motherboard you lose access to your Windows license by the way

Comment: @Ramhound Removed.

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy My questions are not about hardware shopping recommendations. I only needa know if it's possible to upgrade this PC model, if I could use the same power supply, if I could use the same chasis and what components can be upgraded. No brands and links needed.

Comment: @Ramhound Even though I've got a Windows XP CD and a Windows 7 CD?

Comment: If you have a BOX Windows license, you can move it to another PC (ie. new motherboard). OEM licenses are bound to one motherboard model and can't be transferred. You basically want to build a new PC, but reuse old case, PSU and HDD, I wouldn't call that an upgrade. By the way, "Intel Core i3 3.70Ghz" doesn't tell us much, there are [dozens of i3 CPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i3_microprocessors) and at least three of them come with 3.7 GHz clock.

Comment: If you're on the low end, price out prebuilt machines as well. In *some* cases they may end up being cheaper, especially if you're trying to cut corners on a build like this. That said, a PC these days will easily last for a decade or so, so its worth taking that into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question because it requires delving far into the distant past (of computers, which change very rapidly).

The short answer is that your PSU is compatible with the ATX12V 2.0 spec (it has 24 pins on the motherboard main power connector as evidenced [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C6NMVYC)) and might just barely be powerful enough to work, but your case is a BTX form factor (I wasn't able to figure out which version) and may not be compatible with ATX or Micro ATX motherboards.

"Early" BTX motherboards were so similar to ATX that they were interchangeable, meaning you could put an ATX motherboard in a BTX case. And since Micro ATX is just ATX with only 2 out of the 3 screw holes used, it would work if your case is designed that way.

But the BTX standard diverged from ATX, to the point that they flipped the motherboard completely around in the BTX standard, arranging the componentry differently. If you have such a BTX case, then trying to slot ATX or Micro ATX motherboards in that case will cause the back panel header to face toward the front, which won't work. If you oriented the back panel header to face towards the back of your case, it would either be upside down, or the motherboard itself would be upside down -- neither configuration will work.

You'd be much better off buying a cheap low-end Micro ATX case and a modern low-end PSU instead of trying to re-use 10 or 12 year old componentry with a new system. I understand that you're building this on a low budget, but I'm telling you this isn't very likely to *work* at all (you'd end up physically sawing off parts of your case to hack something together, but instead of doing that you're probably better off putting your computer components inside a $2.50 cheap plastic storage container or something.

Comment: Not to mention its just old enough to have a non standard PSU. Dell did silly things with pinouts.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and explanation. I've only one more question. Can I use the same periferals and monitor? or does that have compatibility issues as well?

Comment: Monitor, yes, but Its probably going to be terrible compared to modern monitors. Backlight tech and such have improved. You'll either need a DVI-I port with an adaptor or a VGA port for an old monitor. Keyboard and mouse ought to work - modern PCs still have PS/2 and USB ports.